# How can I make the arrow keys work in a Rails/Twitter-Bootstrap image slider (carousel) app?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the carousel app from this site http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp work. Everything works fine except for the left and right arrow keys. The environment I'm using is just a plain ordinary Rails app environment. I'm using the twitter-bootstrap-rails (https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails).

I did some debugging and found out that if I manually include the jQuery and Bootstrap libraries, the arrow keys will work. I did this by:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    render layout: false
  end
end
```

Then copying and pasting the entire example from the website I mentioned above to the view. As I understand it, this controller/view setup does not load any of the layout, Javascript, stylesheets, etc.

A similar thing can be achieved if, in the app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file, I put this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of the default contents:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

I also tried removing the turbolinks argument pair but the arrow keys still would not work.

What am I missing? How do I debug this in a systematic manner? I tried following the events being fired on a browser's development tool (Chrome profiler) but I can't seem to narrow down the actual left/right arrow key press event from all the output.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `bootstrap.min.js` and `jquery.min.js` files to your assets directory: `app/assets/javascripts`.  Also be sure to require them in your application manifest: `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`.  If you have jQuery or bootstrap gems in your Gemfile, remove them.  These steps will achieve the same effect as adding these two lines to your layout:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The example should still work but at least now you're setup will match the traditional Rails environment.

Monitor your javascript console in chrome's web inspector to see if any javascript errors come up while using the plugin.

---

If you want to override the keypress events try this:

```
<script>
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
    $("#myCarousel").carousel("prev");
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
    $("#myCarousel").carousel("next");
  }
});
</script>
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem already does that because the Bootstrap components already appear on my pages and jQuery code already works, without adding those two files. Everything works fine except for the left/right arrow keys. BTW, I also tested this by issuing an alert when I press a key, and the page does indeed receive a keypress event.

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted to make sure your version of bootstrap and jquery match the example (gems tend to always be a version behind).  See my edit for overriding the keydown events.